# How to specify an exact match for a single file in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a php nginx web site for which I defined default locations. This works fine except that I can’t get the favicon.ico to be returned. The favicon.ico file is stored at the root of the root directory.

I currently have this:

```
location / { error_page 404 = @pmwiki; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location @pmwiki { rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?n=$1 last; }
location ~ ^/(cookbook|local|scripts|wiki.d|wikilib.d) { deny all; }
location ^~ /docs { autoindex on; types { text/plain php; } }
location ~ \.php$ { . . . }
location ~ /\. { deny all; }
```

I need to add the following, but don’t know what to put in place of the question marks.

```
location = /favicon.ico { ???? }
```

Comment: Probably the only statement you need is `root /path/to/directory;` specifying the directory containing the file `favicon.ico`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I already have a root statement above the list of `location` statements, but when I copy pasted the root statement in place of the ???, it worked. Is there a way to avoid the root path copy ?

Comment: Yes. Don't do it. `location = /favicon.ico { }` will inherit the value of `root` from the surrounding context.

Comment: @RichardSmith this is strange. I tested this and it didn’t work. Now it works. Thank you very much. If you provide an answer, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need anything between the `{}`. An empty block will inherit values from the surrounding context for many of the directives, including the current document root.

So the simplest solution to point the URI `/favicon.ico` to the file `/path/to/root/favicon.ico` is:

```
root /path/to/root;
...
location = /favicon.ico { }
```